# Apache Kafka Streams: How to switch from using In-memory Key Value Store to Persistent Key Value Store?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My current code uses InMemoryKeyValueStore, which avoids any persistence to disk. I want to use Stores#persistentKeyValueStore. My current code is as follows:

```
static StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> makeStoreBuilder(
            final String storeKey,
            final Serde<LinkedList<StoreItem>> valueSerde,
            final boolean loggingDisabled) {

        final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> storeBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(storeKey), Serdes.String(), valueSerde);
        return storeBuilder;
    }
```

For me to use Stores#persistentKeyValueStore, do I just change the call like this:

```
final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> storeBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeKey), Serdes.String(), valueSerde);
```

May I know whether this is the right way to change this and if it will have any implications? I'm very new to Kafka and the Streams API and would appreciate some insight.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(topicName) will persist state to disk. Please make sure:

- that you have enough disk space allocated
- set appropriate retention period for the data

I see that you have disabled logging, is that done intentionally?

Comment: Hi Aishwarya, yes I disabled it intentionally. I have checked the disk space allocated. May I know why checking the retention period for the data is important here?

Comment: @Rebecca depending on how much data get stored in the disk you may want to change the default retention period. If your application receives too many events it may cause your disk to explode.

Comment: If you disable logging, you might loose the state, even if you use a persistent store. Fault-tolerance is only guaranteed by logging; the persistent store is not fault-tolerant itself. The purpose of a persistent store is mainly to allow you to hold data that does not fix into main memory.

Comment: @aishwaryakumar Would you be able to guide me on setting retention period for persistentKeyValueStore? Somehow I couldn't find it in documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores.html#persistentKeyValueStore)